# Get 2nd digit from minutes

Tags: javascript

What i want to do is only get the 2nd digit from minutes.

So if minutes i 01 i only get 1.

if minutes is 33 i only get 3.

if minutes i 59 i only get 9.

What i have in javascript

```
var d = new Date();// get date

var m=d.getMinutes();//get minutes from date
```

I dont know were to go from here?

Can someone help me in the right direction?

I gues i need to do something like

```
  m%10
```

But it didnt work.

Comment: You guess you need something like `m%10`? Then try it!

Comment: m%10 is exactly what you need. Are you having a problem with it?

Comment: it didnt work thats why i put something before it ;)

Comment: You need to assign the result of `m%10` to something. It could even be `m` again.

Comment: Then provide a real question like ... When I try to do `m%10` in `<this code>` I get the following error....

Comment: Guys! I have a better approach: `+m.toString().replace(/^\d?(\d)$/, "$1")` :)

Comment: @VisioN you should wrap that in a `parseInt()` ;)

Comment: @Basic No need in `parseInt` when there is a magic `+` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m%10` does work.

```
var d = new Date();// get date
var m=d.getMinutes();//get minutes from date

var secondDigit = m%10;//get second digit
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/gAG76/1/

So yes, I guess it is what you needed.

Answer (score 4):

m%10  will work what you need

```
var m=33;

m%10 will give 3 // it will give the remainder
```

or `var m = d.getMinutes() % 10;`

http://jsfiddle.net/SLD5n/2/

Comment: @Sven B did you solved your problem

Comment: You're correct, but you've got both digits the same in your fiddle, so it doesn't really showcase the effects. I'd suggest changing one of the 3's.

Comment: Yes i solved it i guess i made a typo somewhere ;)

Comment: cant accept answer in first 7 minutes

Answer (score 3):

You probably want this:

```
var d = new Date();
var m = d.getMinutes() % 10;
```

or perhaps

```
var d = new Date();
var m = d.getMinutes();
var digit = m % 10;
```